# Error: CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected

Tags: c#, delegates, callback

I am currently working on a third party dll, and randomly when the delegate `OnReceive` is invoked I get the following error:

> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected

I read that `GC.Collect()` can solve the problem using static but also not as, I have hours and trying every way `CallbackOnCollectedDelegate` get the error, please help...

```
namespace Interfaz
{
    class TMPDlg:
    {
        public CTMIF m_objTMPInterface;

        public uint m_dwLocalIP;
        public ushort m_nPort;
        public byte m_nSubNet;
        public uint m_nRadioID;
        public uint m_nIndex;
        public uint m_dwMobileID;
        public int nLength;
        public string mensaje_destino;
        public string mensaje_recibido;        


        public TMPDlg()
        {
            m_objTMPInterface = null;
        }

        unsafe public void OnReceive(ushort wOpcode, System.IntPtr pbPayload, uint dwSize, uint dwLocalIP)
          {
              TMReceive(wOpcode, (byte*)pbPayload, dwSize, dwLocalIP);
          }

        unsafe public void TMReceive(ushort wOpcode, byte * pbPayload, uint dwSize, uint dwLocalIP)
          {
             // Some Work....
          }

        public void Send_PrivateMsg(string textBoxMensaje, string labelID)
        {
            m_nRadioID = uint.Parse(labelID);
            mensaje_destino = textBoxMensaje;
            nLength = textBoxMensaje.Length;

            m_objTMPInterface.SendPrivateMsg(m_nRadioID, mensaje_destino, nLength, 0);

        }

        public void conect_master(ushort port, string ip)
        {
            m_objTMPInterface = new CTMIF();
            m_dwLocalIP = (uint)IPAddressToNumber(ip);

            ADKCALLBACK myOnReceive = new ADKCALLBACK(OnReceive);
            m_objTMPInterface.SetCallBackFn(myOnReceive);

        //m_objTMPInterface.SetCallBackFn(OnReceive);        
            m_objTMPInterface.OpenSocket(m_dwLocalIP, port, m_dwMobileID, 10)<

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this part is the problem?

```
ADKCALLBACK myOnReceive = new ADKCALLBACK(OnReceive);
m_objTMPInterface.SetCallBackFn(myOnReceive);
```

If you have an *instance* variable of type `ADKCALLBACK`, then so long as your instance isn't garbage collected before (or while) the callback function is executing, you should be okay. What controls your instance's lifetime?

```
class TMPDlg
{
    // Instance variable to protect from garbage collection
    private readonly ADKCALLBACK receiveCallback;

    public TMPDlg()
    {
        receiveCallback = myOnReceive;
    }

    ...

    public void ConnectMaster(ushort port, string ip)
    {
        ...
        m_objTMPInterface.SetCallBackFn(receiveCallback);
        ...
    }
}
```

(As an aside, your naming could be improved significantly, and you should avoid having public fields.)

Comment: I will test, thank you very much for your time to have help. I commented on the brevity :)